# codigo css corrompeu apos erro de sistema

Tags: html, css, recuperação-de-erros

olá preciso de ajuda urgente, estava trabalhando no pc de repente o pc parou e reiniciou, quando voltou, meu arquivo css estava corrompido e agora ele aparece no código varios losangos com interrogação, tem alguma forma de recuperar isso, pois senão vou ter que refazer todo o css do site, apesar de estar usando bootstrap, uma boa parte eu criei classes novas, tem efeitos é muita coisa pra refazer.

[RESOLVIDO]
Abri o codigo-fonte pelo firefox onde ainda não tinha atualizado o cache do navegador e vi que estava tudo lá ainda, aí foi só copiar novamente para o IDE. Porém acho que muita sorte mesmo, não acho que seja uma solução, mas por via de duvidas, se acontecer algo parecido, é bom testar em outro navegador diferente do que se costuma usar talvez assim, como no meu caso, dê certo! Obrigado à todos.

Comment: Verificou se está no formato utf-8?

Comment: olá, sim, o netbeans está configurado para salvar em utf-8, porém o pc reiniciou bruscamente, então voltou dessa forma, receio que tenha corrompido de alguma forma, agora ele aparece em branco.

Comment: Se não me engano existem uns "conversores" on line que vc cola seu código e ele corrigi, mas vc vai ter que pesquisar....